# philosophers dining deadlock in python

Tags: python

I am implementing philosophers dining problem, however I get an error that

```
            # Pick up the forks                                                 
            forks[self.left_fork].acquire()
            locked = forks[self.right_fork].acquire(False)
            if locked == True:
                break
            forks[self.left_fork].release()
            forks[self.left_fork], forks[self.right_fork] = forks[self.right_fo\
rk], forks[self.left_fork]



            # Put down the forks                                                
            forks[self.right_fork].release()
            forks[self.left_fork].release()
```

It prints that

```
1 is eating
2 is eating
3 is eating
```

and then gives that error

Comment: What are you expecting it to print?

Comment: i don't expect it to freeze and have an error and with a given time all 5 should eat right?

Comment: What's the deal with the breaking if both locks are acquired? That doesn't seem to make sense -> Once a single philosopher grabs two forks(locks), those two forks would never be able to be used again.

Comment: i was trying to implement http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers#Python

Comment: Notice that in that example there are two loops: One within `run` which calls `dine`, and one within `dine` that contains the code for attempting to pick up forks. If that solution works for you I recommend that you use that one and avoid making your own until you have a better understanding of the algorithm.

Comment: is there some small fix up for this problem that i have?

Comment: because I probably should use kind of the way i have it because i was given those layouts that had a deadlock, and i just added the pick up forks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you appear to be releasing one of the locks twice.  First you acquire the left_fork lock:

```
forks[self.left_fork].acquire()
```

And later release it:

```
forks[self.left_fork].release()
```

You then switch the two locks over in your forks list, so the released lock is now in `fork[self.right_fork]`:

```
forks[self.left_fork], forks[self.right_fork] = forks[self.right_fork], forks[self.left_fork]
```

And after the sleep you release the locks again:

```
forks[self.right_fork].release()
forks[self.left_fork].release()
```

That leads to the error.  Looking at the code, presumably the first `release()` call is the incorrect one.

Presumably the intent was to check if the attempt to lock `right_fork` failed, and release `left_fork`, which should look something like this:

```
# Pick up the forks                                                 
forks[self.left_fork].acquire()
locked = forks[self.right_fork].acquire(False)
if not locked:
    forks[self.left_fork].release()
    break
```

Comment: this however, feeds 0,2,4 people, why is that?

Comment: You might be running into problems swapping the locks (I don't remember that being part of the problem when I was learning it).  Also, this solution to avoid the deadlock doesn't guarantee any individual will get both forks.